# Typing an object property decorator

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have many objects of functions like so

```
const functionsObject = {
   a: () => {/* does stuff */},
   b: () => {/* does other stuff */},
}
```

I wrote a decorator that logs access to any of these functions, but I'm struggling to type it properly. Without the `// @ts-ignore`, Typescript complains that  *type string cannot be used to index type T*. I understand why it says that, but I can't figure out how to get rid of it. Here's my code:

```
export const decorateWithLogging = <T extends { [functionName: string]: (...args: any) => any }> (functionObject: T) => {
  for (const key of Object.keys(functionObject)) {
    const fn = functionObject[key]
    // @ts-ignore <--- ** I want to get rid of this **
    functionObject[key] = function(...args: any) {
      console.info('Calling function:', key)
      return fn.call(this, ...args)
    }
  }
  return functionObject
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, what version of typescript? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wCbCVAhjYAdQEsYALAGQgHNrjlq4BeOAHgBU5QDkNU4A3nADaAMwCuyBDGIoAcrgC2wAFxx0UetQC6agBQA6I7ijVUa3MgCeASmYA+OJatwAvvb0SpMlAHkARgBW2DBq7HZMjgIAUHBxcKLQcHpIaPAA1sAuEKJwAcHSBplWqJ6S0rLI+SE2djHxDYgo6AnIzAnlPlVBIcLF2rGNcQD0w3AAAjCoALTE1MjQwGzTK3AAVGtwAJJwAO6W8DAQcNTA8JoYcDlw5MT8G4NDXhV+PdJ9Wdrtz13JRgYmMwWax1R5DeKpVAQAA2wAM9ESegA5ABhXDQ6FaDreSoqJEAGjgxRsYPBcCgZ3EUDaomQBgQ6OheluqEJ-0BqBJZNcYJ5DQpMCpNM6lWq0miriAA

Comment: yea, just delete the `// @ts-ignore` and you'll get the error! I'm on 3.7 but don't think it matters.

Comment: Wow, I am dumb, I should read comments. Anyway, I'll add an answer with some fixes

Comment: Actually, the easiest way to do this is just to remove the type parameter and make it's constraint the type annotation for functions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If I understand what you're saying, you're suggesting
`decorateWithLogging = (functionObject: { [functionName: string]: (...args: any) => any }) => {...}`. That does get rid of the TS error here I mentioned, but unfortunately it's not really plausible, because it loses all the type information about functionObject. I.e. `const decoratedObject = decorateWithLogging(functionObject) // now decoratedObject is of type [functionName: string]: (...args: any) => any }, we lost all info about what it actually contains`. We somehow need the best of both worlds:/

Comment: That's a valid point, but your Decorator function doesn't need to return, it does everything by mutating its input